# dataframe manipulation using iterrows with a subset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to manipulate this dataframe given their ID's,initial amount and  balance, 
this is my desired dataframe, with desired_output being the the column i make:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{"ID" : [1,1,1,2,3,3,3],
 "Initial amount": [7650,25500,56395,13000,10700,12000,27000],
"Balance": [43388,43388,43388,2617,19250,19250,19250], "desired_output": [7650,25500,10238,2617,10720,8530,0]})
```

This is my current code:

```
unique_ids = list(df["ID"].unique())
new_output = []
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    this_adv = row["ID"]
    subset = df.loc[df["ID"] == this_adv,:]
    if len(subset) == 1:
        this_output = np.where(row["Balance"] >= row["Initial amount"], row["Initial amount"], row["Balance"])
        new_output.append(this_output)
    else:
        if len(subset) >= 1:
            if len(subset) == 1:
                this_output = np.where(row["Balance"] >= row["Initial amount"], row["Initial amount"], row["Balance"])
                new_output.append(this_output)
            elif row["Balance"] - sum(new_output) >= row["Initial amount"]:
                this_output = row["Initial amount"]
                new_output.append(this_output)
            else:
                this_output = row["Balance"] - sum(new_output)
                new_output.append(this_output)

new_df = pd.DataFrame({"new_output" : new_output})
final_df = pd.concat([df,new_df], axis = 1)
```

Essentially what I want to do is if there is only 1 unique ID (len(subset) == 1) then use the first if statement.  Anything else that has more than 1 ID  (len(subset) >= 1) use the other if statements.  I'm not getting the output that I want, how would you guys approach this?

Thanks! any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your algorithm is attempting to calculate the rolling sums of `Initial amount` for each `ID`, and then calculate the value of each row for `new_output` in part based on how an `ID`'s current period `Balance` compares to previous period's rolling balance for that same `ID`.

If we start with your sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{"ID" : [1,1,1,2,3,3,3],
 "Initial amount": [7650,25500,56395,13000,10700,12000,27000],
"Balance": [43388,43388,43388,2617,19250,19250,19250], "desired_output": [7650,25500,10238,2617,10720,8530,0]})
```

We'll need to first create temporary columns to store ID counts (what you referred to above as `len(subset)`) and then the rolling balance for each ID.

```
val_cts = pd.DataFrame(df['ID'].value_counts().reset_index().rename({'ID': 'ID Count', 'index': 'ID'}, axis=1))
df = df.merge(val_cts, left_on='ID', right_on='ID')
df['rolling_balance'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Initial amount'].cumsum()
```

We'll also create a column to contain the `new_output`:

`df['new_output'] = 0`

At this point the `df` looks like this:

```
    ID  Initial amount  Balance desired_output  ID Count    rolling_balance   new_output
0   1   7650            43388             7650         3               7650            0
1   1   25500           43388            25500         3              33150            0
2   1   56395           43388            10238         3              89545            0
3   2   13000            2617             2617         1              13000            0
4   3   10700           19250            10720         3              10700            0
5   3   12000           19250             8530         3              22700            0
6   3   27000           19250                0         3              49700            0
```

Now for the meat: I wrote a function which I believe encapsulates the algorithm you were trying to implement with your if-statements:

```
def calc_output(count, init_amt, bal, cur_roll_bal, prev_roll_bal):
    if count == 1:
        return init_amt if bal > init_amt else bal
    else:
        if bal > init_amt:
            return init_amt if bal > cur_roll_bal else bal - prev_roll_bal
        else:
            return bal-prev_roll_bal if bal-prev_roll_bal > 0 else 0
```

Apply the above algorithm to each row:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    # Make sure not at first row belonging to an 'ID'
    if i > 0 and df.iloc[i-1]['ID'] == row['ID']:
        prev_idx = i-1
    else:
        prev_idx = i
    row['new_output'] = calc_output(row['ID Count'], row['Initial amount'], row['Balance'], row['rolling_balance'], df.iloc[prev_idx]['rolling_balance'])
```

Then drop the columns we used in our calculation: `df = df.drop(['ID Count', 'rolling_balance'], axis=1)`

Then the dataframe looks like this:

```
    ID  Initial amount  Balance  desired_output  new_output
0   1             7650    43388            7650        7650
1   1            25500    43388           25500       25500
2   1            56395    43388           10238       10238
3   2            13000     2617            2617        2617
4   3            10700    19250           10720       10700
5   3            12000    19250            8530        8550
6   3            27000    19250               0           0
```

My `new_output` value in the 4th row is 20 less, and the `new_output` value in the 5th row is 20 greater than their corresponding `desired_output` values, but I'm hoping that this is due to the fact that those values were initially incorrectly entered into your example dataframe above.